# Search through all levels of a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

Apologies if this is a duplicate question, I'm not familiar with the exact terminology for what I'm trying to achieve so I've been unsuccessful in searching for an answer thus far. I'm pretty green with this stuff, and the following has come about through trial and error - not because I'm under any illusions that it's right.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Using a textarea, clients enter custom opening times (one per line): day (name), date, status (open or closed), opening time, closing time. For example: 'Christmas Day,2016-12-25,closed' or 'Boxing Day,2016-12-26,open,8:00,17:00'.
2. This textarea content is split into an array by new line, and then split again by comma.
3. Using these arrays, search whether the date is today's date and, if it is, show more content from the arrays (like the opening time for that particular day), or - if there's no match - display regular opening hours (already set elsewhere).

What I've got so far (note that I've already retrieved the $custom_dates variable content):

```
$array = array();
$array = preg_split('/\R/', $custom_dates); /* split by line break */
foreach($array as $key => $custom_dates) { 
   $array[$key] = explode(',', $custom_dates); /* split again by comma */
};
```

This returns the following array (which could also be longer or shorter depending on the client's needs):

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
      (
         [0] => Christmas Day
         [1] => 2016-12-25
         [2] => closed
      )

  [1] => Array
     (
        [0] => Boxing Day
        [1] => 2016-12-26
        [2] => open
        [3] => 8:00
        [4] => 17:00
    )
)
```

What I'm struggling with is how to search for a specific date match in all of the arrays. If I use **if($array[$key][1] == $date)** (where $date is already set to be today's date based on my timezone) then it only searches the last array, which in this case is the Boxing Day information. So if $date is 2016-12-26, then everything's great and it will go ahead and show the Boxing Day opening times.

But if today's $date is 2016-12-25 then - even though there's information specific to this date - nothing happens because the $key in my if statement is only checking the Boxing Day array information. This means that continuing to check the rest (whether open or closed, etc.) is redundant because it's not even getting the date right.

My (long-winded) question is: what can I use instead of $array[$key][1] in order to search all of the array levels to find a match for that last [1]? Or have I come at it from the completely wrong angle?

Please help me out if you can, I'm pulling my hair out because I don't know the right terms to search for. Happy to provide more details if you need any.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try using `for` or `foreach` loop

Comment: @tms, if the answer worked for you, please accept it. If not, please add a comment about what else might be a factor or consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would accomplish that inside the foreach loop you've already created.

```
$array = preg_split('/\R/', $custom_dates); /* split by line break */
foreach ($array as $key => $custom_date_string) {
    $custom_date = explode(',', $custom_date_string);
    if ($custom_date[1] === $today) {
        // do stuff
    }
    $array[$key] = $custom_date; // if you still need this
}
```

Comment: I guess this `$custom_date = explode(',', $custom_date_string);` should come before foreach

Comment: @Ms.Nehal - I don't understand your comment. You wouldn't even have access to the $custom_date_string variable outside the scope of the foreach loop. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks @pdom - this really steered me in the right direction and everything is working as I need it to. 

If you have time, I'd really appreciate it if you could provide a brief explanation of your solution, so I can figure out why your explode behaved differently to mine (other than the obvious differences in appearance)?

Thanks again. :)